# remove jquery promise listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm use jQuery.Deferred and promise to listen for updates across my JS classes.
How can I remove a progress handler when i no longer need it.

```
//some place in the code:

var $deferred = $.Deferred()
    $promise = $deferred.promise();

/// them sometimes:
$promise.notify('use requests action');

// somewhere else:
$promise.progress(progessHandler);

function progessHandler(msg){
   console.log(msg);
}

// then later
// how do I unsubscribe from the progress update?
$promise.?????(progessHandler);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery.proxy() - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: If you are abusing promises as event emitters, stop this practise and implement proper pub/sub pattern. Promise handlers cannot be unsubscibed. However, the notifications will end anyway when the promise is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm familiar with standard event systems which is why i want to do the above. I don't see one for jquery that can be used outside the dom. Or am i wrong about this?

Comment: @jay, proxy helps with what scope a function runs in.